# C++ error codes global namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

i have got errors on visual studio 2010.
i m using c++ and use opencv

Error C2039: 'exit' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
error C2873: 'exit' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration

Comment: We need your code to understand your problem.

Comment: Have you imported exit()? Show us your code?

Comment: #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

 return 0;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

before using `::exit()`.

Comment: Or `<cstdlib>` and `std::exit()`.